# Logstash - adding a certain field with a certain value

Tags: logstash-grok

Here is an exmple of event message:

```
{
"timestamp":"2016-03-29T22:35:44.770750-0400",
"flow_id":45385792,
"in_iface":"eth1",
"event_type":"alert",
"src_ip":"3.3.3.8",
"src_port":21,
"dest_ip":"2.2.2.2",
"dest_port":52934,
"proto":"TCP",
"alert":{
    "action":"allowed",
    "gid":1,
    "signature_id":4027,
    "rev":0,
    "signature":"FTP Successful Login",
    "category":"",
    "severity":3
    },
"payload":"MjU3ICIvaG9tZS9uZXd1c2VyIg0K",
"payload_printable":"257 newuser",
"stream":0,
"packet":"AFBWo0NoAFBWoxZWCABFAABJKDpAAEAGCGcDAwMIAgICAgAVzsbd4MhqOBOjfoAYAOMYcwAAAQEIChHN4EQHnwugMjU3ICIvaG9tZS9uZXd1c2VyIg0K"
}
```

And I'd like to be able to identify the string `"newuser"` (comes always after the number `"257"`) and to create another field named user, and to add the `"newuser"` string into it.

My Logstash config file is the following:

```
input 
    beats 
        port => 5044
        codec => json
        type => "SuricataIDPS"


output 
    elasticsearch 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        #document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
```

How can I extract the `"newuser"` string and to add a new field with that value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define  `filter`  stanza  in your config with `grok` filter, see below:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
        codec => json
        type => "SuricataIDPS"
    }
}

filter {

   grok {
      match => ["payload_printable", "257 (?<user>.+)"]
      tag_on_failure => []
   }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        #document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

And if I want to add a condition, for example, checking other field.

Comment: You can use  if-else if-else statement: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html

for example:

`if [proto] == "TCP" {
   grok {
      match => ["payload_printable", "257 (?<user>.+)"]
      tag_on_failure => []
   }
}`